# Trying to change the number format while plotting plotly bar graph

Tags: graph, formatting, numbers, plotly, range

[image: image1]

[image]

Trying to convert the image 1 to 2 ,the data comes from a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated a dataframe as you did not provide in your question
- have generated both plots from same dataframe
- second plot have used [cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to generate bins, plus reformatted bins to match format in your image

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({"orderNumber": [str(o) for o in range(1000, 1020)], 
                   "Resolution in days": np.random.randint(1, 25, 20)})

px.bar(df, x="orderNumber", y="Resolution in days").show()

df["bin"] = pd.cut(df["Resolution in days"], bins=[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25])
px.bar(
    df.groupby("bin", as_index=False).agg({"orderNumber": "count"}).assign(
        bin=lambda d: d["bin"].apply(lambda s: "-".join(re.findall("[0-9]+", str(s))))),
    x="bin",
    y="orderNumber").show()
```

[image]